# Using RecoverySystem to install an update.zip

Tags: android, android-source, recovery

Good afternoon,

I'm using

```
RecoverySystem.installPackage
```

to install a ROM that I've pushed to /sdcard/update.zip but am getting the following error code in ClockworkMod Recovery:

```
E:Invalid command argument
Finding update package...
E:unknown volume for path [/storage/emulated/legacy/update.zip]
E:Can't mount /storage/emulated/legacy/update.zip
Installation aborted.
```

Can anybody help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to work when I placed the update.zip file into `/system/`.